# facing issue to iterate list in drools

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, drools-planner, drools-fusion, drools-flow

facing problem with List iteration in drools

**GoodsShipment** has the list of **GoodsItems** and 
**GoodsItem** has the list of **Documents**

my requirement is, need to check atleast one document is available or no.

iam tried this 
but failed

**writen a class to checking purpose**

```
public class CheckDocument {

    public boolean flag = false;
    public CheckPreviousDocument() {
    }
    public boolean getPreviousDocument(GoodsShipment goodsshipment) {
        List<GoodsItem> list = goodsshipment.getGoodsItems();
        Iterator<GoodsItem> itr = list.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            GovernmentAgencyGoodsItem document = itr.next();
            if (document.getDocuments().size() > 0) {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
}




rule "previousDocuments minimum 1"

    when
        $o: GoodsShipment()
        %x: CheckPreviousDocuments(previousDocuments($o) == false)
    then
        insert(-------------)
end
```

can anyone please help me..
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is somewhat unusual, but thus rule should do. Note that I have used `Document` as the type for the elements in the list returned by `GovernmentAgencyGoodsItem.getDocuments()`.

```
rule atLeastOne
when
    $gs: GoodsShipment()
    List( size > 0 )
    from accumulate ( $gi: GoodsItem() from $gs.getGoodsItems() and
                      $d: Document() from $gi.getDocuments();
                      collectList( $d ) )
then
    // $gs contains at least one Document
end
```